# Display last DIV on top of display: grid CSS property during media queries

Tags: html, css

I have div with css property `display: flex` on normal browser width and change into `display: grid` on media queries.
[image]

```css
.teal-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.description{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.image{
  background-color: blue;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1440px) {
  .teal-container {
    display: grid !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
  }
```

```html
<div class="teal-container">
  <div class="description">Description here</div>
  <div class="image">Image here</div>
</div>
```

The problem is when it becomes `display: grid` the last div (image div) is bottom of the stack/grid

css during media queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1440px) {
  .teal-container {
    display: grid !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
  }
```

[image]

**I want to display the last div (image div) on top during `display: grid` media query**:

is there a way to do it without re arranging on `display: flex`? Thank you[image]

Comment: have you tried using `flex-direction: row-reverse` on the blue container?

Comment: Please post your code instead of screenshots. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes, this question was to be answered quickly if you have provided the code you have tried.

Comment: I added some codes already. Thank you

Comment: `direction: rtl; ` add this into the css of the grid container class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **flex-direction: column-reverse;** on media query.

`Note:` Check on **Full page** and resize browser.

```css
.teal-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.description{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.image{
    background-color: blue;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .teal-container {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="teal-container">
    <div class="description">
        Description<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus in, hic quia vero aliquam non recusandae autem quibusdam esse amet voluptas, delectus odio quos tenetur iure facilis est officiis. Nisi!
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcbpv.jpg?s=48&g=1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Rifat for the answer. It was `flex-direction: column-reverse` but you have to omit the `display: grid` property and added `align-items: center` to center both divs

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1440px) {
  .teal-container {
    flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `order` on your flex or grid items

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/order

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1440px) {
  .teal-container {
    display: grid !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
}
 .description{
    background-color: yellow;
    order: 2;
  }
  .image{
    background-color: blue;
    order: 1;
  }
}
```